# how to convert integer to boolean in android

Tags: android, integer, boolean

i have this one:

```
int life=3;

if (life=2){
   txt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
else if (life=1){
   txt2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
else if (life=0){
   txt3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
```

but i got error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean". So, can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Use double equals. if (life==2)

Answer (score 3):

`==` stands for comparison and `=` for assignment. So you need this

```
int life=3;

if (life==2){
   txt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
else if (life==1){
   txt2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
else if (life==0){
   txt3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
```

> > FYI , if() takes **boolean** arguments and not **integer** so the compiler
> >     is telling you the same in
> >     error

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains about the `if` statements, since you're passing an `int` value (`life = 2`) instead of a `boolean` (`life == 2`). Replacing assign operator (`=`) by equals operator (`==`) it's ok, but for this scenario you should consider changing `if` blocks like that one, for `switch-case` statement.-

```
switch (life) {
    case 2:
        txt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    break;
    case 1:
        txt2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    break;
    case 0:
        txt3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't get error anymore, but when I run the project, these part are didn't work. what must I put in these part so it can be work?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
if (life=2){
txt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else if (life=1){
txt2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else if (life=0){
txt3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

to this

```
if (life==2){
txt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else if (life==1){
txt2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else if (life==0){
txt3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```